# Select In PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

Is there any way to have a CASE SELECT Statement in a PIVOTED Column. My Code is as follows

```
SELECT PName, [RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC] 
FROM 
(
   Query

 ) src 

  pivot
    (
     max(Visits)
    for Discipline in ([RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC])
    ) piv
```

I am getting the output as follows

```
   Pname        RN         HA          LVN        MSW        SC
    AA        AG-2/W    LO-1/W       NA-1/W     SK-2/W     NO-2/MON
    AA        JL-2/W     NULL         NULL        NULL       NULL
```

Because there have been 2 RNs assigned to 1 PN I want to summarize the results only in 1 Row and select only 1 value to be displayed in the RN column so that the result is only as follows based on my condition.

```
    Pname        RN         HA          LVN        MSW        SC
    AA        JL-2/W    LO-1/W       NA-1/W     SK-2/W     NO-2/MON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to remove the data AFTER the pivoting, because [RN] itself is subject to a MAX condition, i.e. it is itself a pivot column.  Wrap it in a CTE, apply a RowNumber() function and partition correctly, then filter it for just 1 row per partition.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT PName, [RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by PName order by [RN] ASC) RowNum
    FROM 
    (
       Query

     ) src 

      pivot
        (
         max(Visits)
        for Discipline in ([RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC])
        ) piv
)
SELECT *
  FROM CTE
 WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full query, you should be able to apply a row_number to the inner query and then use a `WHERE` clause similar to this:

```
SELECT PName, [RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC] 
FROM 
(
   <yourQuery>, row_number() over(order by somefield) rn -- add a rownumber here
 ) src 
pivot
(
    max(Visits)
    for Discipline in ([RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC])
) piv
where rn = 1
```

If you post your full query, there might be other ways to do this.

edit, using your info from a previous question, your query would be like this:

```
select patname, [HA], [MSW], [RN]
from 
(
  select patName, Disc,
    sname+' '+schedule new_value,
    row_number() over(partition by patname, disc order by disc) rowNum
  from yourquery
) src
pivot
(
  max(new_value)
  for disc in ([HA], [MSW], [RN])
) piv
where rownum = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91612/6)

Or you can use:

```
select *
from 
(
    SELECT PName, [RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC] , row_number() over(partition by PName order by PName) rn
    FROM 
    (
       <yourQuery>
     ) src 
    pivot
    (
        max(Visits)
        for Discipline in ([RN], [HA], [LVN], [MSW], [SC])
    ) piv
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: @user1764540 when you place the `rownum` in the outer `where` what are the results?  Why do you say it does not work?